# For a square matrix $X$, do we have that: $\|X\|_2^2=\|X^TX\|_2$, where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes operator norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Let $X$ be a $n\times n$ matrix. I think that $\|X\|_2^2 = \|X^{\top}X\|_2$, because:

$$\|X^{\top}X\|_2^{2} = \max_{\|x\|_{2}=1} x^{\top}\left(X^{\top}X\right)^2x=\rho\left(\left(X^{\top}X\right)^2\right)=\left(\rho\left(X^{\top}X\right)\right)^2 = \|X\|_{2}^{4}$$

Where $\rho$ denotes the maximum eigenvalue / spectral radius of $X$.

Is this calculation correct?

Comment: What is $\rho$?

Comment: Sorry.$\rho$ is max eigenvalue.

Comment: I've edited your post to instead write: $\|X\|_2^2=\|X^TX\|_2$ which is what I think you meant, based on the calculations that you've shown - please correct me if that is not what you intended. As far as I know, your calculations look correct.

Comment: Thanks. I've miswritten.

Comment: Welcome. For future reference for typing mathematics on this site, you should include *everything* mathematical inside the dollar signs: I notice you wrote: `Let X be an n$\times$n matrix` when instead you should format it as follows: `Let $X$ be an $n\times n$ matrix`, or if you enjoy boldface matrices: `Let $\mathbf{X}$ be an $n\times n$ matrix`, which renders as: "Let $\mathbf{X}$ be an $n\times n$ matrix."

Comment: Thank you for your very courteous reply!

Answer (score 1):

You can use formulas
$$\lVert A \rVert^2 = \sup_{\lVert u \rVert = \lVert v \rVert = 1}(Au, Av),$$
$$\lVert A \rVert = \sup_{\lVert u \rVert = \lVert v \rVert = 1}(Au, v),$$
both of which are consequences of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. To get $\lVert X^TX \rVert = \lVert X \rVert^2$, use the above formulas and note that $(Xu, Xv) = (X^TXu, v)$.

The above argument works on an arbitrary Hilbert space.